# File Operations and Processes

Tags: files, process, c

Is it possible that two different processes(parent and child) can see the same text file and manipulate it ?

I accomplished this, but I had to open the file in both processes by using fopen(). My expectation is that one of the processes opens the file and the other one can see and manipulate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the `fork(2)` manual](http://man.openbsd.org/fork.2) on my OpenBSD system (my emphasis):

> The child process has its own copy of the parent's descriptors.
>   These descriptors reference the same underlying objects, so
>   that, for instance, **file pointers in file objects are shared
>   between the child and the parent**, so that an `lseek(2)` on a
>   descriptor in the child process can affect a subsequent `read(2)`
>   or `write(2)` by the parent.  This descriptor copying is also
>   used by the shell to establish standard input and output for
>   newly created processes as well as to set up pipes.

This means that if you open a file in the parent process before forking the child, both processes will have the same file opened.  However, if the child reads from the file, then the parent's file pointer will also be moved.

To access a file in both processes *independently*, you have to open the file in both processes separately.

If you open a file in the parent *after* the call to `fork()`, it will not be opened in the child process, and vice versa.

Comment: Everything is okay for me. There is only one thing that I wonder. Parent process opened the file. After that, child process is forked. In this case, how can child process access the file pointer ? What I mean is whether the file pointer is sent to child process via the parameter argv ?

Comment: @Goktug The child process is an exact copy of the parent. You should be able to just use the file pointer. It was inherited from the parent.

Comment: You are right. Actually, I could not image it and I forgot that they were inherited from parent process to child process.

Comment: I wrote a code in which the child process try to read a file opened by its parent process previously. Actually, the operating system does not let the child process read the file. There is a while loop in both parent and child process to read the file. At first, parent process read some contents of the file. Then, child process is executed and child process's ID is printed. When the execution comes to the while loop which reads the file in child process, operating system continue to execute parent process. In other words, it never executes the while loop in child process.

Comment: @Goktug Since file pointers are shared between parent and child, and if the parent had already reached end-of-file, then any attempt to read from the same file pointer in the child would return end-of-file immediately.

Comment: @Goktug You may post the code with a new question if you wish (and I would look at it), but be aware that too generic C programming questions are better suited for the StackOverflow site.

Answer (score 0):

And here is some example code that does just that.

```
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char buf[8];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ch, fd[2], rv;

    pipe(fd);

    switch (fork()) {
    case -1:
        err(1, "could not fork");
    case 0:                    // child
        rv = lseek(STDIN_FILENO, -7, SEEK_END);
        if (rv == -1) err(1, "could not seek");
        sleep(3);
        close(fd[1]);
        break;
    default:                   // parent
        close(fd[1]);
        read(fd[0], &ch, 1);
        read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 7);
        printf("read '%s'\n", buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what is going on is that the parent blocks waiting for the child and meanwhile the child seeks to the end of standard input, minus seven, then closes the `pipe(2)` to the parent. This unblocks the parent, which reads from the shared descriptor from where the child moved the shared file pointer to.

```
$ make sharedseek
cc     sharedseek.c   -o sharedseek
$ echo asdfasdfasdf123456 > x
$ ./sharedseek < x
read '123456
'
$
```

This will not work if standard input is not seekable. Also the pipe (or some form of communication) is really necessary as otherwise the parent may run before the child.

If the file descriptor was not shared then the parent would not read from where the child moved the pointer to.